# Passing an array onto google charts

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to plot a donut chart using google charts. I am using an MVC frame work, laravel to be precise. I have an array which I am passing to the view uing the compact function.
I really have searched everywhere but can't seem to find anything to point me, please bear in mind I'm quite new to javascript.

I have already tried:

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(? =$frequency ?>);

This is an excerpt of my server side php

```
 {  
    $memberNames = array_keys($frequency);
    $frequency = array_count_values($members);
    return view('contact.stats', compact('frequency'));

}
```

This is googles code for implementing the chart

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     11],
      ['Eat',      2],
      ['Commute',  2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities',
      pieHole: 0.4,
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
   </script>
```

Like I said when I return $frequency, it looks something like this {"female":74,"others":2,"na":63,"male":59}

I basically want to pass $frequency into the var data in the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php is returning a json object (`{}`)
google charts expects an array (`[]`)

just need to convert

```
  var frequency = {"female":74,"others":2,"na":63,"male":59};
  var chartData = [];
  Object.keys(frequency).forEach(function (name) {
    chartData.push([name, frequency[name]]);
  });
```

when creating the google data table,
we need to pass `true` as the second argument to `arrayToDataTable`
this indicates that the first row in the array is data, and not column headings.

```
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData, true);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  //var frequency = <?= json_encode($frequency) ?>
  var frequency = {"female":74,"others":2,"na":63,"male":59};
  var chartData = [];
  Object.keys(frequency).forEach(function (name) {
    chartData.push([name, frequency[name]]);
  });
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData, true);

  var options = {
    title: 'My Daily Activities',
    pieHole: 0.4,
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="donutchart"></div>
```